# How to get last modified time from pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am using pysftp to access files on SFTP. But I want to get the last modified date of these files and store it in mongo. This is to access the date again next time I run the code.
I cannot find a function that returns me the date of the file.

```
class My_Connection(pysftp.Connection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if kwargs.get('cnopts') is None:
                kwargs['cnopts'] = pysftp.CnOpts()
        except pysftp.HostKeysException as e:
            self._init_error = True
            raise paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException(str(e))
        else:
            self._init_error = False

        self._sftp_live = False
        self._transport = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._init_error:
            self.close()
```

This is my connection class.

How can I get the date of the file that I am accessing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve a timestamp of a single specific file, use [`Connection.stat`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.stat). It returns [`SFTPAttributes`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes) instance, which has `st_mtime` field with Unix time.

```
mtime = sftp.stat(remote_path).st_mtime
```

---

But if you need to retrieve timestamps of all files in a folder, calling `Connection.stat` for each would be ineffective. You already have the timestamps in the directory listing. The [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) returns `SFTPAttributes` of all files in a directory.

See also [How to sync only the changed files from the remote directory using pysftp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47459065/850848)

---

*You better use Paramiko though: [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.